# How to install a web server to connect to android client

Tags: android, zend-framework

I have a wesite witten by zend framework? I want to build an android's client to communicate with the website? What I need to install? Should I zend Server?

Answer (score 0):

Website?  Install a web server, like IIS or Apache, and deploy the app on it.  Then get your Android phone to connect to the app on your web server.

Comment: Thank duffymo. but i wonder what server android phone can connect? Can I use xampp Server?

Comment: I think clients can make HTTP connections.  That's the protocol web services use.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, that's weenie town. I installed a zend server on my android phone - cut out the middle man.